# Out of memory prompt VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I’am trying to write a code that would check the version number in one workbook against the version list in another workbook in a master spreadsheet that is located in a URL. Everything works fine and instructions are competed however Im constantly getting “out of memory” prompt any ideas why?

```
Option explicit 
Sub test()

    Dim MyPath as Object
    Dim WorkbookType as Range 
    Dim Version as Integer 
    Dim CurrentVersion as Integer 
    Dim SearchRange as Object
    Dim WorkbookVersion as Range 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Version = Worksheets(“sheet1”).Range(“Ver”)
    Set WorkbookType = Worksheets(“sheet1”).Range(“Typ”)
    Set MyPath Workbooks.open(Filename:=“https://LocationOfTheMasterSpreadsheet.xlsm”, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)

    Worksheets(“Master”).Activate
    Set SearchRange = Worksheets(“Master”).Range(“Type”)
    Set WorkbookType = SearchRange.Find(What:=WorkbookType, lookIn:=xlValues)
    Set CurrentVersion = WorkbookType.Offset(0, 1)

    If WorkbookType is nothing then
        Msgbox “No such data found”
    End If
    If CurrentVersion = Version then
        Msgbox “ success this is a current version”
    ElseIf  CurrentVersion <> Version then 
        Msgbox “Sorry you’re not using Current Version “
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please **indent** your code when posting...

Comment: `Worksheets(sheet1).Range(“Ver”)` do you mean `Worksheets("sheet1").Range(“Ver”)`, or maybe `sheet1.Range(“Ver”)` ?

Comment: There are a bunch of errors in here which might or might not be a result of posting from your phone.  Maybe wait until you can copy/paste the actual code on a computer?

Comment: @TimWilliams ok I think the above has been updated now. Any Ideas what's the root of the problem with "out of memory" prompt ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in there which would cause "out of memory" unless that workbook you're opening is huge.  Is there any other code which might be running?

```
Sub test()

    Dim MyPath As Workbook
    Dim WorkbookType As Range
    Dim Version As Long
    Dim CurrentVersion As Long
    Dim SearchRange As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'neither of these need to be Range types...
    Version = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("Ver").Value
    WorkbookType = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("Typ").Value

    Set MyPath = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="https://LocationOfTheMasterSpreadsheet.xlsm", _
                               ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)

    Set SearchRange = MyPath.Worksheets("Master").Range("Type")
    Set WorkbookType = SearchRange.Find(What:=WorkbookType, _
                             LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    'test before trying to get CurrentVersion
    If WorkbookType Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No such data found"
    Else
        CurrentVersion = WorkbookType.Offset(0, 1).Value
        If CurrentVersion = Version Then
            MsgBox "Success this is a current version"
        Else
            MsgBox "Sorry you’re not using the Current Version (" _
                      & CurrentVersion & ")"
        End If
    End If

    MyPath.Close False 'close without saving

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The workbook is't huge and essentially the code boils down this part. I have tried all the suggestions i.e. Application.Calculation etc. I even added an error handler. The prompt comes up randomly. Is there another way I could open the workbook that is stored on URL to compare it's value against another workbook and display the message accordingly?

Comment: What you're doing should be fine.  There's nothing in your posted code which looks like it would cause the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and was able to fix it by simply adding `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` under `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and then reverting back to `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` under `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`.

Additionally, Tim William's code is also slightly cleaner which may help.